# Reliable solution to copy/paste Vim macros

Tags: vim, vim-macros

[image]

Line number `7` shows the paste of a macro I recorded. When I copy/paste it, the following 4 lines is what I get. I know we can replace `^[` character using `<ESC>`, but thats not just one, there is `^M` & that too in many places. It doesn't seem to be a scalable way to get things done. I feel there is a better way to deal with this than by manually replacing the special characters. If anyone is aware of a better solution, please suggest?

Comment: i can not reproduce it, do you have the same behaviour if you start vim with `vim -u NONE` ?

Comment: How do you "copy/paste" it? Using `y` and `p` shouldn't do what you describe.

Comment: It can't be reproduced easily, I have a plugin that modifies the search to enable PCRE compliant regex. But, the question remains, there should be a solution to handle such characters right?